# dynamixel_control no motor found /dynamixel mx-64AR, usb2dynamixel

Tags: ros, dynamixel-controller, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am trying to use the new robotis servo: dynamixel MX-64AR, but I cannot find the servo both in win8 and ubuntu 14.04.
in win8, I tried to use RoboPlus Wizard to search all the bps, nothing found...
in Ros, I run: `roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial controller_manager.launch`,
and I got:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dynamixel_manager/namespace: dxl_manager
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/baud_rate: 57142
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/max_motor_id: 25
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/min_motor_id: 0
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/max_motor_id: 25
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/update_rate: 20
 * /rosdistro: indigo

 * /rosversion: 1.11.10

NODES
  /
    dynamixel_manager (dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [23510]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to c01c22cc-d87a-11e4-9915-001aa0aa3777
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23523]
started core service [/rosout]
process[dynamixel_manager-2]: started with pid [23540]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:92: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.motor_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('motor_states/%s' % self.port_namespace, MotorStateList)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:93: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.diagnostics_pub = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', DiagnosticArray)

INFO] [WallTime: 1427898245.997934] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 0 through 25...

[FATAL] [WallTime: 1427898248.149759] pan_tilt_port: No motors found.
```

and I am sure of this :

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0 

crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0  4月  1 22:51 /dev/ttyUSB0 ....
```

About the HW, I use usb2dynamixel, RS485 -4p interface, and the switcher is in the middle.

the power support is a takasago ex-375l, I set output as 12.5 v, 0.4A, the motor led flashed when it's powered  on.

And I had checked the 4p cable, all the four lines are good.

About the ros version;

```
rosversion dynamixel_controllers

0.4.0

$ dpkg -p ros-indigo-dynamixel-controllers | grep Ver

Version: 0.4.0-0trusty-20150305-1931-+0000
```

about the bps in the launch file, the parameter of the servo is link:[here](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-64at_ar.htm), the default bps of mx-64ar should be 57142.... I had tried 57142, 57143, 57142.9 and 1000000, no one works.

I am really screwed here.......................
HEEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLPPPPPPP!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206414/dynamixel_control-no-motor-found-/dynamixel-mx-64ar,-usb2dynamixel/) by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-03**:
What version of dynamixel package are you using? Add to your original question the following command result for the future refenrence:

```
$ rosversion dynamixel_controllers
0.4.0
$ dpkg -p ros-indigo-dynamixel-controllers | grep Ver
Version: 0.4.0-0trusty-20150327-0507-+0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, finally, I went to the Robotis Shop, and they test my motor and a new mx-64ar and an AX series motor, however, only the AX motor can work. So it seems like that this batch of mx-64ar productions have a lot defectives.
What's a bad luck, a defective pesters me 5 days....................

---

Originally posted by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) with karma: 43 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) on 2015-04-03**:
one more thing just for reminding the followers, with the new mx-64ar I exchanged from the shop, everything works well, but the default baud of this motor is 57143.....if you want to ping it  through "controller_manager.launch". note that 57142 doesn't work here, although it works in RoboPlus.